# Fluids in absence of gravitational field

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Consider a fluid kept in a vessel in the absence of any gravitational field. Obviously, the fluid will have no forces to keep it stationary inside the vessel. Thus it should move in the space randomly. Now, my question is how exactly will the fluid behave? I know it can no longer form a free surface, so what kind of form would it take? Will there be any pressure developed inside the bulk of the fluid? What would now prevent the liquid from expanding like a gas?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can see an astronaut playing with water on the ISS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKk_7NIKY3Y

It can not move in the space randomly, it is moving as the forces affecting it want to. There is no random movement in the Newtonian mechanics.

If there is no gravity, there are still forces acting on the fluid, most important among them is the [surface cohesion](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-biology/chemistry-of-life/structure-of-water-and-hydrogen-bonding/a/cohesion-and-adhesion-in-water). It tries to decrease the surface of the liquid, i.e. to collapse it into a sphere.

The liquid can also clog to surfaces anywhere.

Without gravity, there is no hydrostatic pressure. But still there is the pressure of the environment. In the example video, that is the $\approx$ 1 atm pressure of the air inside the ISS.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. However, could you explain if it is possible to compute the size of the fluid sphere?

Comment: Also what exactly happens to the fluid pressure?

Comment: There is no hidrostatic pressure, but still there is the pressure of the environment armosphere. This is 1atm in the case of the ISS.

Comment: Ideally, if the fluid can do everything what it wants to, then it becomes a perfect sphere. It size (diamater) depend on the fluid volume: $V=\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3$.